# PHP file is not refreshed after fwrite and fclose

Tags: php, file, fwrite

I am doing following:

```
$configurationFile = fopen($configurationFilePath, 'w');
$result = fwrite($configurationFile, $newFileContent);
fflush($configurationFile);
fclose($configurationFile);
if ($result) {
    echo '<pre>'; var_dump(require('file.php')); die();
...
```

And the old data is shown, though in my editor or after the page refresh I can see the new content.

How do I force PHP see the new file content right after `fclose`?

Comment: can you post where you set $configurationFile?

Comment: @engvrdr added, if I understood you right

Comment: Try if calling `clearstatcache` helps.

Comment: Well then I’d probably just make a redirect after writing the config file, so that whatever resource you want to display after that gets loaded “fresh”. (You could perhaps also use `eval` instead of require, since you have the file content in a variable at that point already – but if that’s a good and reliable solution is rather doubtful.)

Comment: @CBroe for some reason even after redirect the file is cached somewhere, the only thing that really helps is reloading a page, but may be I am missing something.

Comment: @Ivan do you have any opcode caching enabled? I would check that if i were you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @engvrdr for the hint. The problem was with OPcache extension and I ended up with two ways:

1. Disable OPcache:

   `ini_set('opcache.enable', '0');`

I wrote it at the beginning of my index file but it can be tuned up for some particular cases

2. Make script run longer by means of `sleep()` (pretty rough solution)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but you can disable opcode caching for exact files with blacklist file : http://php.net/manual/en/opcache.configuration.php#ini.opcache.blacklist-filename